# How to send SMS based on cell contents in Google Sheets

Tags: object, google-apps-script, twilio-api

This is a follow up to my last question [How to loop an onEdit function to send emails from multiple rows in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533837/how-to-loop-an-onedit-function-to-send-emails-from-multiple-rows-in-google-sheet) Now to finish this project, I need to be able to send SMS based on a cell's contents.

I'm using Twilio, and the code from their example https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html allows me to send texts to ALL numbers in the spreadsheet when I run the function. There is some help at this question [Send SMS from Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498715/send-sms-from-google-sheet) however since I'm using Twilio instead of carrier emails I'm still getting stuck.

As of right now, this first block of code allows all texts to be send at the same time I run the function (sendSMS contains all API info and is not shown):

```
function sendAll() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HIVE');
  var startRow = 2; 
  var width = 16;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, width) 
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    try {
      response_data = sendSms(row[4], row[12]);
      status = "sent";
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      status = "error- Not Sent";
    }
    sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 2).setValue(status);
  }
}
```

I tried replicating the pattern used to send the emails in my last question by inserting:

```
if (sheet.getSheetName() == sheetname && range.columnStart == 1) {
    var data = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 21).getValues()[0];
    var object = {
      to: data[5] // Column "E"
    if (e.value == "Appt. Set (send text)") {
      object.subject = "Appt. Confirmation";
      object.body = apptText; // variable containing body text

      if (object.subject) sendSms(object);
```

I've updated the code to where it will trigger onEdit, but only for the first IF statement:

```
function onEditText(e) {
  var sheetname = "HIVE";
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var timezone = "GMT-5";
  var timestamp_format = "MMMM dd 'at' HH:mm";
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
  var twilioNumber = 1234567890;

  if (sheet.getSheetName() == sheetname && range.columnStart == 1) {
    var data = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 21).getValues()[0];
    var object = {
      to: data[5] // Column "E"
    };
    var apptText = "Hey " + data[9] + "! \n\nThanks...;
    var leadText = "Hey " + data[9] + "! \n\nThanks so...;
    var followText = "Hey " + data[9] + "!  \n\nAre...;
    var confirmText = "Hey " + data[9] + "! ⏰ \n\nYour appointment...;

    if (e.value == "Appt. Set (send text)") {
      object.subject = "Appt. Confirmation";
      object.body = apptText; //
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),2,1,1).setValue('Appt. Set Text sent on ' + date);
    } else if (e.value == "Lead (send 1st text)") {
      object.subject = "Lead";
      object.body = leadText; //
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),2,1,1).setValue('Lead 1st Text sent on ' + date);
    } else if (e.value == "3rd Text") {
      object.subject = "Follow Up";
      object.body = followText; 
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),2,1,1).setValue('3rd Text sent on ' + date);
    }else if (e.value == "Day of Confirm (send text)") {
      object.subject = "Can't wait to meet you!";
      object.body = confirmText;  
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),2,1,1).setValue('Confirmation Text sent on ' + date);
    }
    if (object.subject) sendSms(data[5], twilioNumber);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're assigning `object.subject` two lines before  `if (object.subject) sendSms(object);` the last line will always evaluate as true so `sendSms()` will always run. The Twilio documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/send-sms-during-phone-call-node?code-sample=code-create-a-new-sms-message-for-your-caller-4&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=default) suggests that the second parameter passed into `sendSms()` should be a `twilioNumber not a message body. Can you provide more of your code as your if statement is open-ended and I don't understand its evaluation.

Comment: I'm passing (to, body) because of what the tutorial says here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html but I'm trying your suggestion now. I also updated the code above to show more of what I'm trying to do with the if statements. Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: What structure does the sheet you are reading from have? I've got the `sendAll()` function working from the tutorial you posted but it just takes the number and message body from the example Sheet using `response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);`. Also the trigger function for a bound script to a sheet is `onEdit(e)` not `onEditText(e)`.

Comment: What is the `err` you're getting on the failure of sending a mail? Have you set up an installable trigger in your G Suite Developer Hub?

Comment: There's no error for sending an email, that works perfectly after I made the changes suggested in my previous question (linked at the beginning of this post). Now I'm just trying to update the code from the twilio tutorial. It currently sends out sms to every row at when the function is triggered, but I want it to only send one text at a time onEdit when the cell contents of a particular row match the corresponding if statements in the code. I promise I'm really trying to communicate this correctly, and I appreciate your patience!

Comment: Where is the message body for the SMS being stored in the sheet? You already have the if statement which gets the edited value and checks to see if it's from Column A, can you not just insert an `sendSmS(number, messageBody)` inside the if blocks so it sends them at the same time as the email?